# javascript-Vue src binding not displaying the images

Tags: image, binding, vue.js

I'm creating a simple web app that takes a JSON file which holds an url of 6 images stored inside my folder.

Here is the file: https://api.myjson.com/bins/t3ri9 and I want it using vue js's vue-bind:src to attach each url of each image so that they may be displayed on the browser. Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div id="main">
      <br/><br/>
      <h2>Here is a list of all your image</h2>
      <br><br>
      <div id="images">
        <div class="image" v-for="image in pod">
          <img v-bind:src="image.url"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name: "wall",
          data() {
              pod: []
          },
          created() {

this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/t3ri9').then(function (data) {
                this.pod=data.body;
                console.log(this.pod);
              });
          }
        }
    </script>

    <style scoped>

    </style>
```

However when I run the project on a localhost it doesn't display the images even though when I do to the console it correctly passed the image's url.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the callback is not the same this as outside (in `created() {`).
Use fat-arrow function to preserve `this` from the outside:

```
this.$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/t3ri9').then((data) => {
                this.pod=data.body;
                console.log(this.pod);
              });
```

Comment: Thant doesn't matter the data is being received properly and stored in the pod array. I am able to print out the image url in a <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

v-bind:src="require('image.url')"

I'm guessing your local images aren't added by webpack?

Maybe try and use the remote location of the image instead.

http://...